# sign up only for admins but not regular user - RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am developing an android application and I am developing the server using Ruby on Rails. I want only admins to be able to access the application database. That is, the server home page should contain a "sign in" (for admins to sign in.. only 2-3 persons are gonna be admins) link but shouldn't contain a "sign up" link to prevent unauthorized users signing up. Basically, I don't want any random person to sign in to the admin page. How do I do this?

Alternatively, what I can do is keep the "sign up here" link on the home page (with a line saying "admins only") and allow people to register but refuse users to sign in saying "sorry, u are not recognized as an admin"> I believe I can do this by hardcoding admin ids into my code and checking them everytime someone signs in... But this just looks lame

Or I can remove the signup link altogether (only keep a sign in link) and create admins's accounts from the terminal itself from my local machine on which server is running, thus preventing any random user from signing up. Again, this looks inconvenient..

This is my first time on web development and I have little knowledge about this. Please help! Thanks!!

Comment: If you're using Devise in the Rails app for authentication, simply remove the `:registerable` option from your User model. Then no-one can sign up.

Comment: Rails does not provide any registration by default, so that feature exists because either you added a gem or you wrote it. In any case, you must deactivate the feature if you don't need it, not hide it from html. The best answer is @sevenseacat comment if you use devise (please, specify what you use).

Comment: I am kind of writing my own code for authentication system. The solution Billy has posted seems interesting. Will try that out and see if it free of common loopholes. Thanks guys for such quick responses :)!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like ActiveAdmin. This also helps you in developing the admin-pages quickly. You could define the Admins directly in the seed data and only those users will be able to login into the admin panel. As there will be no signup link/functionality that comes up with AcftiveAdmin, I believe - it should fit your purpose.

http://www.activeadmin.info/

Answer (score 0):

This basically looks like an invitation only sign up. Since the case is simple, nothing shy about hardcoding invitation token in code.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :match_invitation

  def match_invitation
    params[:invitation_token] == 123456
    # Or set it as an enviroment variable using Figaro gem
    # params[:invitation_token] == env['invitation_token']
  end
end

# View
<% if match_invitation %>
  <%= render partial: 'sign_up' %>

# Signup controller
class RegistrationController
  before_filter :check_invitation

  def check_invitation
    unless match_invitation
      return redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are not allowed to sign up"
    end
  end

end
```

Usage, give the link with token to persons you allow to sign up

```
www.example.com/sign_up?invitation_token=12345
```

Comment: This looks really nice! Will try this out. Just what I was looking for. Instead of hardcoding the admins, just use a complex token and pass it with the url to sign up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inconvenient about creating users from your console, it's the quickest and easiest solution.
I'd even remove the sign-in link from your page, and access it by manually adding /signin to your home pgae url.
If it's just 2, 3 people managing the app, you can hack as much as you can.

ActiveAdmin is also a good option, but it depends on what you want your admins to be able to do. If it's just managing a blog content or an ecommerce backend you don't need to bother installing and configuring it.